# Is there a standard public URL convention used on a Wordpress site directly to a page listing all of a user's public content?

Tags: uploads, users, content, list

Is there a standard convention for a full direct public URL address that, when visited/clicked on, will show a page list all of user account's public content uploaded on that site.

Background:

I have an account with getmedia.org.uk Podcasting site and here is my home page/user profile page:
http://www.getmedia.org.uk/members/therobyouknow/

However it only lists *'recent content'* but I know I have earlier content not shown on that page.

I have recently contacted the site admins but haven't heard back from them yet and not sure if they are in a position to resolve my query so I thought I would ask here.

To further illustrate my point I'm looking for something like:
getmedia.org.uk/members/therobyouknow/content
or
getmedia.org.uk/members/therobyouknow/all
or
getmedia.org.uk/members/therobyouknow/uploads

to list *ALL* of my content

**Update:**

- I don't want an answer based on search engine results - because:

  1. I want a URL of the site because it's direct and part of the site
  2. The Google URL is messy
  3. The google URL could change as they develop their search
  4. The google URL may include other sites the refer both to the site and me
  5. The google search results have superfluous and unrelated information (ads, links optiond etc) making it harder to read, if messy for such a
- Just to pre-empt any other unhelpful contribution: This question is *not* a self-promotion of myself or my content by stealth to readers of wordpress.stackexchange.com. It is a genuine query. That said, I would like to use the URL on profiles of myself but know that others would find a similar solution useful for their posted wordpress content, so it's for me *and* others.

Comment: The question is to specific for one site, it's impossible to tell how the theme was written, voting close.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a standard wp url, but if you just want to know what pages are attributed to you on a particular website then you could try google - ie: 
https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site%3Agetmedia.org.uk+therobyouknow ?

Comment: Yes, Google might do this. But please add an explanation ... don't just drop a URL in here as an answer.

Comment: Updated. I'm aware of the site guidelines but I just can't think of anything more to say.

Comment: Yes I *know* google can return *search results* of pages attributed to me on a particular website. I should have mentioned that to pre-empt this kind of answer. I don't want this answer for several reasons: 1) I want a URL of *the site* because it's direct and part of the site 2) The Google URL is messy 3) The google URL could change as they develop their search 4) The google URL may include other sites the refer both to the site and me 5) The google search results have superfluous and unrelated information (ads, links optiond etc) making it harder to read, if messy for such a kind of query.

Comment: P.S. @Aces I didn't down vote you myself.

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering .. if you tried to navigate via pages and construct a URL

What I mean is that author page template is basically the archive page template so you can construct a URL with page navigation like so

*http://damien.co/author/damiensaunders/page/2*

You might also find that *http://damien.co/author/damiensaunders?&paged=2* works